# Intelligencia UrlRewriter force lowercase URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, url-rewriting

What is the best way to force lower case URLs on rewrite?

- Global.asax?
- web.config?

All has failed...what am I doing wrong? See the following:

**Global.asax**

I don't know which method to use?

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string path = Request.Path.ToLower();

        context.RewritePath(path);
    }
```

**web.config**

I have tried using the web.config method but can't manage:

```
<rewrite url="(.*)$" to="$1" permanent="true" />
```

How can I change the above code so that it automatically force the url to lower case?

Comment: Reason why I'm doing this, is because I have been building a website for more than a year and to go through the whole site and replacing uppercase urls will be a nightmare

Comment: Why would you need to replace urppercase urls? Your urls are case-insensitive right?

Comment: That is correct, but someone told me that lower case urls are better for SEO... is that correct?

Comment: Not particularly. Also, if you're thinking that Google "might" have an issue, use a canonical link in your page: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: Thanks for this... so UpperCase characters won't negatively effect my google results at all then?

Comment: As far as I know it wont negatively effect your Google result. Having the Canonical link in your page with the lowercase URL will tell Google that the uppercase version is actually the lowercase version accessed via a different url (If they even check the letter case these days)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the URL rewrite module for IIS?

[http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt6HG.png)

There is a particular rule for lower case: 
[image]

Comment: Great extension but it creates a redirect in the background. Redirect causes POST to loose its data so it won't work.

Comment: Have you tried to add condition to ignore post?
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />

Answer (score 1):

There us no way you can force `your user` to write lower case urls. All the urls `you` generate can be lower case. If you get a uppercase in your url you can redirect your user to a lowercase version.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Request.Path;
    if (ContainsUpperChars(path))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Request.Path.ToLower());
    }
}

bool ContainsUpperChars(string str) { some code to test for uppercase chars }
```

Comment: normally you start with a get, if you redirect the gets all posts should be lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Use the url rewrite tag in the web.config.
If vs2012 does not recognise the tag, run the script found on this page:
http://blog.vanmeeuwen-online.nl/2013/04/visual-studio-2012-xml-intellisense-for.html
Here are two other links that i used to figure things out.
[ScottGu'sBlog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension) and 
[Meligy's Blog](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/09/01/asp-net-mvc-seo-lowercase-url-iis-rewrite-net45-nuget/)

```
<system.webServer>                                               
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```